# Apache settings issue in AWS Ubuntu LAMP

Tags: lamp, aws

I am using Ubuntu version in AWS hosting. We installed Drupal 7 in the hosting. I am facing the issue with rewrite in Apache module.

While restarting the Apache server, I am facing the below errors (because of this, rewrite module is not working probably)

Following are the errors:

```
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-xxx-xx-x-xx

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `ServerName` as suggested in the error?